# How to add line before match within given line range/patterns using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to do a basic `sed`-line insertion but withing a given line range.

Using given sample file `sample.txt`:

```
foo
tomato
apple
bar
START_MARKER
tomato
apple
kiwifruit
pineapple
strawberry

END_MARKER

apple
qux
```

I want to add a line (say "_____new_line_____") before any line between "START_MARKER" and "END_MARKER" that contains "apple".
My sample would then become:

```
foo
tomato
apple
bar
START_MARKER
tomato
_____new_line_____
apple
kiwifruit
_____new_line_____
pineapple
strawberry

END_MARKER

apple
qux
```

I tried:

```
sed '/^START_MARKER$/,/^END_MARKER$/ /apple/i _____new_line_____' sample.txt
```

But I get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown command: `/'

Also tried:

```
sed '/^START_MARKER$/,/^END_MARKER$/ {/apple/i _____new_line_____}' sample.txt
```

But I get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

If I wanted to add a "_____new_line_____" line before all line containing "apple" (not using START_MARKER and END_MARKER) the following would work:

```
sed '/apple/i _____new_line_____' sample.txt
```

I am missing something to chain/combine the /start/,/end/ pattern selection with my //i add-line-operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GNU sed`

```
$ sed -e '/^START_MARKER$/,/^END_MARKER$/ { /apple/i _____new_line_____' -e '}' ip.txt
foo
tomato
apple
bar
START_MARKER
tomato
_____new_line_____
apple
kiwifruit
_____new_line_____
pineapple
strawberry

END_MARKER

apple
qux
```

Everything after `a/c/i` command is considered as the argument for that command. So, you need to separate them using newline or `-e` option as shown above. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline for more details.

With other `sed`, this might work, but not sure as I can't test it:

```
sed '/^START_MARKER$/,/^END_MARKER$/ {
/apple/i\
_____new_line_____
}' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
sed '/START_MARKER/,/END_MARKER/!b;/apple/ i_____new_line_____' sample.txt > out
```

where `sed` goes through every line and if the pattern 'apple' is in the range of START_MARKER and END_MARKER, it inserts '_____new_line_____' before 'apple' and if the pattern 'apple' is not in the range, then it does nothing.

If you don't direct the output to a file then it will print on the terminal screen.

Comment: Hello, what is the `!b;`, and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/START/{:a;n;/apple/i\__newline__' -e '/END/!ba}' file
```

This inserts a line before any line containing `apple` between `START` and `END` or the end of the file.

To insert a line only between `START` and `END` before a line containing `apple` use:

```
sed -e ':a;/\n/{/^[^\n]*apple/i\__newline__' -e 'P;D};/START/{:b;N;/END/!bb;ba}' file
```

This gathers up the lines between `START` and `END` and only then inserts a line before the lines containing `apple`.